# problem with matrix exercise about null space and singularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning linear algebra on my own, using an e-book. An exercise is the following:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ matrices and let $C=A−B$. Show that if $Ax_0=Bx_0$ and $x_0≠0$, then C must be singular.

Now, as far as I could tell, the notation $x_0$ was never defined in the book, but I guess that
$Ax_0$ means $A$ times the vector that multiplies $A$ to give the zero vector.

My first question, is that true?

My second question is how to solve this. The solution I could find online is:

$Cx_0 = (A-B)x_0 = Ax_0 - Bx_0 = Ax_0 - Ax_0 = 0$

I don't understand how can this is correct, because we start with what I will note as $x_0^c$, the vector that multiplies $C$ to give $0$. Which means, we get

$Cx_0^c = (A-B)x_0^c = Ax_0^c - Bx_0^c$ and we have no reason to assume $Ax_0^c = Bx_0^c$. we only know that $x_0^a = x_0^b$

So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $Ax_0 = Bx_0$ we have $(A-B)x_0 = 0$, and thus $C x_0 = 0$ (the same $x_0$) since $C = A - B$.

This shows that $C$ there is a nontrivial solution ($x_0 \ne 0$) to $Cx=0$, and thus $C$ is singular.